# Display the details from one table and count from another table

Tags: mysql

need to fetch id, name, address details of a man from one table and and number of properties from another table belonging to him

we tried this way

select person.* count(property.id) from person, property where person.id = property.id

Comment: You are missing a comma: `select person.*, count(property.id) `

Comment: But this displays total count of property. We actually need is property belonging to a particular person

Comment: My comment is not an answer. I'm just pointing at one issue. If you want a good answer, you should describe your tables and the relation (foreign key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
select person.id, person.name, person.address,
       count(property.id) 
from person
left join property on person.id = property.id
group by id, name, address
```

Group by all fields that are not aggregated (counted). And then use the explicit join syntax. The other is just outdated since decades.